# Is it ok to let each method open a connection to the database?

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, npgsql

This code, part of 1 method, will call 3 others methods

```
 .. 
    var userId = LookUpLocalUser(userName);

    if (userId == 0)
    {
        userId = InsertUser(userName, userName);

        AddRoleToUser(userId, (int)Roles.Admin);
        AddRoleToUser(userId, (int)Roles.User);

    }
    guid = LoginUser(userId);
..
```

Each of these methods (LookUpLoacalUser, AddToRole, LoginUser) will do something on the database. So my question is. What is better, to let each method open a connection to the database(and close it, using `using`) or should I open just one connection and pass it to each method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, But make sure that you **Close** those **connection** at the end.